# Spring Batch: read csv file into Map

Tags: spring, spring-boot, csv, spring-batch

I have data in a csv file that I want to read into a Map using Spring batch. The format of the data is like this:

1, "data1", 2, "data2", 3, "data3"

This format lends itself easily to a Map, but I can't seem to do it. I am currently using a PassThroughLineMapper and then tokenizing the String in the processor. However, since I have a couple of processors, I am having to do this in all of them. This seems very inefficient to me. Here's my current FlatFileItemReader code below.

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<String> reader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<String>()
            .name("fileLineReader").linesToSkip(1)
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(inputCsv))
            .lineMapper(new PassThroughLineMapper())
            .build();
}
```

I would like it to return Map<Integer, String>

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a simple task in the end. I wrote a custom lineMapper. Not deleting the question because it might help somebody else.

```
@Override
public Map<Integer, String> mapLine(String s, int i) throws Exception {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] tokens = s.split(",");
    String key = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++) {
        if (tokens[j].equals("9999")) {
            break;
        } else {
            if (j % 2 == 0)
                key = tokens[j];
            else
                map.putIfAbsent(Integer.valueOf(key), tokens[j]);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```